# Branching strategy for special releases

Tags: mercurial, branch, release

Later this week we are doing some tests on an embedded device. For this, we want to know exactly what software was tested, but we also have to make some modifications to it for testing purposes. The current strategy we use is based on the popular ["A successful Git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). What we want is

- Not bloat the current structure.
- Visually easy to distinguish what was tested and what has been changed since.

We are leaning towards an unnamed branch with a tag at its head as it keeps the named branches to releases and features, but is still easy to find visually.

What would be the drawbacks of this approach and what other approaches are suitable?

Comment: I use a simplified version of the same branching model, and assuming you mean "Bookmark" instead of "tag" at the unnamed branch head, then I've found that this approach has worked very well for me.The bookmark can be used as a tag for a revision specification in exactly the same way as a tag or branch.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, bookmark is a much better alternative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawback is similar to what a named branch offers: it's a permanent marker (though you can re-tag, thus move a tag).

However the better alternative is in this case to use a bookmark as that's by design a transient name which can be added or (re)moved to any revision you like at any time.

Comment: Come to think of it; wouldn't we want a permanent marker? After all, it is strictly that revision that was tested. When next test is due, we can merge the latest release branch into the unnamed test branch and with a bit of luck and clever design, it should be directly testable and we can assign a new tag for the second test?

Comment: Of course, you can do that. And depending on how you manage your revisions and how your tests are designed, a tag might be exactly what you want. For instance useing like 1.2.3-beta1 or 1.2.3-featureA.rXXXX etc for subsequent (internal) test releases might just be what you want.

Comment: Personally, I have set my compile farm with Jenkins such, that it compiles both: the head(s) of each push made to that repository, as well as any tagged revision it receives (which I consider releases in that case). However with this approach I do not see the tested versions which do not have a tag. So for your case a tag might indeed be best option, if you want to quickly see from the repo itself what has been tested.